# Can different Azure Classic Services share the same IP-address?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

**Background**

I have three environments for my Azure Classic Web Service:

1. Development
2. Staging
3. Production

Currently they each run as a different Service, with corresponding reserved IP-Address.

**Question**

I would like all the instances to share the same IP-address on hostname:

- development.myservice.com
- staging.myservice.com
- production.myservice.com

I looked into deployment slots, but firstly I can't seem to be able to share the same IP-address accross multiple slots (am I wrong?), and secondly it doesn't look like I can add more slots to a Classic Web Service (which by default has *Production* and *Staging*.

Should I be using a Gateway service? Virtual Network?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You probably could do this with a reverse proxy or similar, but what advantage do you see in using the same IP for all 3, rather than 1 IP each?

Comment: The reason is that the sites talk to third party that grants access to only one IP-address at a time (they allow one IP-address/API-key pair per tenant/API-key is bound to one IP-address).

Answer (score 0):

**As best i know :**

Based on Azure platform you are able to integrate **one shared ip address** for an example staging , development and production environment as you stated in your question .

I've do **recommended** to try with point all instances into one ip address with below scenario :

> Choose and install a Server Virtual Private Network service on one instances
>   names as A NIC ether1 then try with install and integrate all other
>   instances client virtual private network services name as B,C,D to connect A .

I had successfully implemented above solution/scenario in my Azure Lab before .

Comment: Kindly provide more info about your current operating system type , i will include and edit answer for provide full description of how to , detailed tutorial as well . community wiki entry . Thanks for your consideration ./

Comment: It's a .Net solution running on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me here .! 
As you are stating you have .net framework environment over windows platform , i am offering you to going setup A record DNS entry to point all staging bucket into one single ip address will help you out with the question scenario as well . it is a simple way , for sake of save time better than configure reverse virtual private network ..

Comment: I'm sorry Nathanael - I am having troubles understanding what you are writing.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, Actually follow these steps : Open DNS management under administrative tools. Start Menu - Control Panel - Administrative Tools – DNS. you have to create or edit a NEW forward lookup zone in all of your DNS zone webservers with the name "development.myservice.com
staging.myservice.com
production.myservice.com" and create eg a A record with the IP 10.13.23.119 to be able to resolve all buckets into single ip address . remember replace ip "10.13.23.119" with that one you have from your Azure account . hope it's be a clear enough , up vote if you don't mind .!